# Python SQLite supply binding

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have an error I have no supplied a value for binding.

```
def insert_god(id):
with conn:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO gods_attribute_table VALUES (:name, :siege, :initiation, :crowd_control, :wave_clear, :objective_damage)",
    {'Name': id.name,
     'Siege': id.siege,
     'Initiation': id.initiation,
     'Crowd_control': id.crowd_control,
     'Wave_clear': id.wave_clear,
     'Objective_damage': id.objective_damage})
```

I have 6 parameters I want to put in a table. Not sure where the error is

Comment: You're making us guess what and where the error is.  Edit the question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the binding names are case sensitive.  Try the following version where the case is in agreement between your query and the Python code:

```
with conn:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO gods_attribute_table VALUES (:name, :siege, :initiation, :crowd_control, :wave_clear, :objective_damage)",
    {'name': id.name,
     'siege': id.siege,
     'initiation': id.initiation,
     'crowd_control': id.crowd_control,
     'wave_clear': id.wave_clear,
     'objective_damage': id.objective_damage})
```